# Kconfig - defined without a type

Tags: cmake, esp-idf

I´m working on a software component for a RAK3172 LoRa module and I have created a `Kconfig` file for menuconfig, but I got the following warning

```
warning: RAK3172_DEFAULT_BAUD (defined at C:/Projects/firmware/components/RAK3172/Kconfig:11) defined without a type
Loaded configuration 'C:/Projects/firmware/sdkconfig.debug'
```

for this configuration option

```
    menu "Interface"
        config RAK3172_DEFAULT_BAUD
            choice
                prompt "UART default baud rate"
                default RAK3172_BAUD_9600

            config RAK3172_BAUD_4800
                bool "4800"

            config RAK3172_BAUD_9600
                bool "9600"

            config RAK3172_BAUD_115200
                bool "115200"

            endchoice

        config RAK3172_BAUD
            int
            default 9600
            default 4800 if RAK3172_BAUD_4800
            default 9600 if RAK3172_BAUD_9600
            default 115200 if RAK3172_BAUD_115200
    endmenu
```

How can I fix this warning? what is wrong here?